# Should I use an infinitive or gerund to explain the how people can earn money? Context: Get paid to teach Spanish/teaching Spanish

Tags: grammar

Which variant is correct grammatically and is used more often among native speakers?

Comment: Get paid to teach, but get paid for teaching. You should give a whole sentence as a context.

Comment: As @fev says, 'Get paid to teach...' and 'Get paid for teaching...' are correct. 'Get paid teaching...' sounds awkward to me. It seems to mean 'You / I get paid while you are / I am teaching...' and sounds like the activities of 'getting paid' and 'teaching' are simultaneous!

Comment: With *some* verbs after imperative ***Get paid** [for some activity]* it's not unreasonable discard the preposition ***for*** when presenting the activity as a continuous participle *(In some countries you can get paid [**for**] taking care of elderly relatives)*. But as a general principle this doesn't work very well. This is because the *default* relationship between the ***get paid*** and an immediately-following ***-ing*** form is one of ***simultaneity***, rather than ***purpose***.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Yes, 'simultaneity', as I said above...